# Mind-boggling pattern based virtuoso conundrum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My math teacher is a very funny guy. He gave us this "*virtuoso*" math problem:
$$\frac{1}{x(x+1)} + \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)} + \frac{1}{(x+2)(x+3)} + ... + \frac{1}{(x+99)(x+100)} $$

I like math, but I only stick to the what I'm learning. My math teacher teaches our Honours Algebra II classes, our Math Team and our Math Research classes, but I only have him for regular Algebra II. I suspect this is the type of problems he shows to his more advanced classes. I can't help but look at this and feel utterly dumbfounded. I've been trying to solve this problem for 35 minutes, but to no avail. My math teacher loves problems like this. I understand that this is a very advanced, truly virtuoso math forum, that this problem is a very straight-forward problem for mathematicians of your calibre, and that it could very much be wasting your time but I have no choice but to ask for help. Thank you so much for reading this everyone! God speed and quod erat demonstrandum! ∎
p.s. I know that there is a pattern between the denominators but I have no idea how to solve it without writing everything out by hand and working with a least common denominator

Comment: This is far from advance, it is a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). I wonder whether your teacher will teach this in next class.....

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:
$$
\frac{1}{(x+k)(x+(k+1))} = \frac{1}{x+k} - \frac{1}{x + (k+1)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x(x+1)} + \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)} + \frac{1}{(x+2)(x+3)} + ... + \frac{1}{(x+99)(x+100)}$$

Note that $$\frac{1}{x(x+1)}= \frac {1}{x}-\frac {1}{x+1}$$

Similarly $$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}= \frac {1}{x+1}-\frac {1}{x+2}$$

Thus your expression telescopes to $$ \frac {1}{x}-\frac {1}{x+100} = \frac {100}{x(x+100)}$$